# Retain the status of checkbox in search after validation or search

Tags: html, forms, jsp, checkbox, struts

I have a search page which has various search criteria options including a checkbox. 
I want to retain the state of the search criteria so that the person who use the application know what they search for.
I am using  `<input type="text" name="foo" value="${param.foo}">` for the text boxes, but I have no idea how to go about for checkbox.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Did u try the same for checkbox or what else you tried

Comment: @prash I tried the same as well as <td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="x" checked="${param.bar eq 'x'? 'checked' : ''}" Intially i want the checkbox to be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the JSTL tag library like this,

See the `<c:if>`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Search</title>
</head>
<body>

    <font size="+1"> Search </font>
    <form action="search.jsp" method="GET">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Location:</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="location" value="france"
                    <c:if test="${param.location != null && param.location=='france' }">
                checked='checked'
                </c:if>>france<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Do not forget to place jstl.jar in WEB-INF/lib . you can download from [here](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar)

Now, If you do not want to use the JSTL tag [I think that is one you are looking for], you can do like this,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font size="+1"> Search</font>
    <form action="search.jsp" method="GET">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Location:</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="location" value="france"
                ${param.location=='france' ? 'checked=checked' : ''} 
                >france<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know.

Comment: Yes ,I was looking for an option without the JSTL tag and it works fine . Thank you and I appreciate your help. I should have been more specific but your thoughtfullness in giving both the options saved a lot of time and made my day.Thanks.